# Shape with highest difference of Drag Coefficients on opposite sides

Tags: fluid-mechanics

What would be the shape having the highest difference of Drag Coefficients regarding opposite sides?

For example, as per the following table, a hollow semisphere would have respectively Cd=0.38 on one side, and =1.42 on the opposite side. Would there be another shape with greater Cd differences? (with similar Reynolds, around 10^4)

[image: Drag coefficients]

(from Sighard Hoerner's book "Fluid Dynamic Drag", Chapter 3)

Comment: Source for the table or did you write or produce it?

Comment: Yes, sure, sorry. It's a very popular table coming from the Sighard Hoerner's book "Fluid Dynamic Drag", Chapter 3

Comment: Since this is an engineering site, can you explain what you are going to do with this info. Actual dimensions, environment, and materials would help as well.